# Fedora 17 boot hangs after changing to CDM

Tags: fedora, boot, display-manager

I am running the stock Xfce spin of Fedora 17 in a VirtualBox virtual machine, and just installed the CDM display manager via yum. I modified the /etc/cdmrc file to start xfce, and added the following to /etc/sysconfig/desktop:

> DISPLAYMANAGER=/usr/bin/cdm

However, upon reboot the process hangs right after the Fedora logo appears with this:

> Cannot open font file True

Can anyone help me diagnose and troubleshoot this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I would boot in single user mode, and disable your DM (display manager). After that reboot into standard mode, and manually run your DM to catch output you normally cannot grab from an automated DM startup.

Boot into single user: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/s1-rescuemode-booting-single.html

Disabling a service: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/15/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Services_and_Daemons.html